# Get unique post in parent category

Tags: php, categories

I have a parent category and several child categories. I also have several posts that belong to the child categories. Each post can be belong to several categories. I want to know how to query the post table so when I want to show all posts in parent category, I'll get all the post under the child categories. the result have to unique post. Sorry for my bad english.

Here is my code :

```
$cats = get_categories('child_of=95'); 

// loop through the categries
foreach ( $cats as $cat ) {
    // setup the cateogory ID
    $cat_id = $cat->term_id;
    // Make a header for the cateogry
    //echo "<h2>".$cat->name."</h2>";
    // create a custom WordPress query
    query_posts("cat=$cat_id&post_per_page=100");
    // start the wordpress loop!
    if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

        <?php // create our link now that the post is setup ?>
        <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_content(); ?></a>
        <?php echo '<hr/>'; ?>

    <?php endwhile; endif; // done our wordpress loop. Will start again for each category ?>
<?php } // done the foreach statement ?>
```

But I always get the duplicate posts.

Comment: are you get only subcategory post's excluding parentcategory?

Answer (score 1):

you can easily find solutions for this by using google.

-- edit with solution for duplicates --
to filter out your duplicates fill an array with the ids. then check if the post is in the array if not print it , otherwise skip it.
you said you have solution for getting the posts so I won't be typing code for that

```
<?php
$do_not_duplicate = array(); // set before loop variable as array

while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
$do_not_duplicate[] = $post->ID; // remember ID's in loop

//now loop through the array
if ( !in_array( $post->ID, $do_not_duplicate ) ) { // check IDs
// display posts ...
the_title();
}


endwhile;
?>
```

Comment: i can find the solution but not for unique post.

Comment: you should fill an array with the ids.
so first add the id to your array, next, check if the id, is already in the array. Then don't print it.

Comment: i try to find the posts by the parent category

Comment: This is nitpicky, but I do think an accumulator is the way to go. I would check it by index instead of searching the array, as an array could be quite large. For example: `$do_not_duplicate[ $post->ID ] = $post->ID;
if( isset( $do_not_duplicate[ $post->ID ] ) ) { continue; }`

Answer (score 0):

The WordPress loop should be able to handle this for you easily (unless I'm not understanding your question).

Whether you're using the loop and [query_posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts) or your own instance of [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query), simply pass the proper category arguments.

Example:

Parent Category (ID: 1)

Child Category 1 (ID: 2)

Child Category 2 (ID: 3)

```
<?php 
$args = array (
  'cat' -> 1, // Category ID of Parent Category (in this case, 1)
  'posts_per_page' -> 10 // Show 10 posts from this category, set to -1 to show all
);
query_posts($args); 
if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 
?>
  <!-- Do something -->
<?php endwhile; else: ?>
<p><?php _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.'); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```